# Why the "Karpuragauram karunavtaaram.." shloka is recited before any aarti?

Tags: shiva, shloka

I think it is noticeable that before any aarti this shlok is recited before the start of aarti. my question is, is there any reason behind it and is it also happening from past.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Karpuragauram_Karunavtaaram

Comment: -This shloka is generally  recited after completion of all  aaratis And with lighting of kappor or camphor.

Comment: @SwiftPushkar but from where i hail it is recited before the aarti i hope they are not doing it wrong and what is the reason behind it?

Comment: I don't think there is specific rule to recite "Karpoora garam" before Aarti. Karpoora in that Sloka denotes color of Lord Shiva not Camphor.

Comment: It may just be janaachaara ( conventional/popular tradition).

Comment: @moonstar2001 - yes correct , that is just part of tradition , and  IMO we may not find specific answer to such questions in some scriptures also.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Well, as said by [The Destroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer) and others it is not compulsory to recite this Sloka during Arati in **all** Pujas.You might have seen it being done during a **Shiva Puja** & which is quite ok.
Because this Sloka is related to Shiva and not to **Arati Mantras**(also called Nirajana Mantras) in general.

The **Karpura Gouram** term (as said by [the destroyer](https://hinduism.stackexchange.com/users/3500/the-destroyer)) refers to the camphor like white skin colour of Lord Shiva.Similar terms like **"Tushardri Sankasha Gauram"**(white as mountain snow) are [elsewhere](http://www.greenmesg.org/mantras_slokas/sri_shiva-rudrashtakam.php) used with the same purpose.

In Vedic Pujas ,it is customary to recite few  Mantras while offering the various Upcharas.

For **Karpura** (camphor)Arati(during all Pujas) we have the following general Mantra(to be uttered while offering Arati to any Deity).

> Om Idam Havih Prajanam Me Astu DasaViram sarvaganam Swastaye||
>   Atamasani Prajasani Pasusani Loka Sanya Bhayasani||Agnim Prajam
>   Bahulam Me Karotvannam Payo Reto Asmasu Dhatta
>
> Kadali Garva Samvutam **Karpuram** tu Pradipitam|| Aaraartikamaham Kurve
>   Pasya Me Barado Bhavo||

[image]

*The first Mantra is from Yajur Veda.Also note that these Mantras changes with Vidhanas(like Sri Sukta Vidhana,Purusha Sukta Vidhana etc)*

*The Mantra that i have posted does not change with Deities(assuming the Vidhana is same) but some people do sing Stutis of Gods while doing Arati.These Stutis of course varies from Deity to Deity.*

Comment: Well actually, i also previously have in my mind that it is done by habit but it is certainly recites in almost all types of aarti.

Comment: Well certainly its not necessary to chant this sloka while doing aratis to all deities.But no harm as well.

Comment: @UdayKrishna Haha ..now edited.